Resolution of TIN in ArcGIS Pro
I am wondering how do I find the resolution of the TIN's I have created. First, I imported my LAS file of a model I made in reality capture which has (0.004204 units/texel). In ArcGIS I created a LAS dataset followed by LAS dataset to TIN. To retain a high resolution for thinning type I chose 'window size' and thinning method 'closest to mean'. Then for thinning value I made several using various values to obtain really fine detailed TIN's and some that are not very detailed.
I am attempting to make TIN's at various scales of 10m, 1m 10cm and 1m.
How can I find the resolution of the created TIN?
For example, when I check the properties tab under the source tab it shows the following:
Data Type Tin

    Tin window .0030    
    Location C:\Users\thebe\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\SubmarineTIN    
    Triangulation Method Delaunay Conforming    
    Version Current    
    Total Points 496441    
    Total Edges 2978577    
    Total Triangles 992859    
    Z Range -0.486199 - 12.477239    
    Z Unit conversion factor 1.000000    
    Vertical Units Meter    
    Top 45.902622 m    
    Bottom -35.672394 m    
    Left -7.819510 m    
    Right 11.384145 m    
    Projected Coordinate System NAD 1983 HARN StatePlane Hawaii 1 FIPS 5101 (Meters)    
    Projection Transverse Mercator    
    WKID 2782    
    Previous WKID 102261    
    Authority EPSG    
    Linear Unit Meters (1.0)    
    False Easting 500000.0    
    False Northing 0.0    
    Central Meridian -155.5    
    Scale Factor 0.9999666666666667    
    Latitude Of Origin 18.83333333333333    
    Geographic Coordinate System NAD 1983 HARN    
    WKID 4152    
    Authority EPSG    
    Angular Unit Degree (0.0174532925199433)    
    Prime Meridian Greenwich (0.0)    
    Datum D North American 1983 HARN    
    Spheroid GRS 1980    
    Semimajor Axis 6378137.0    
    Semiminor Axis 6356752.314140356    
    Inverse Flattening 298.257222101


What do you mean when you say TIN resolution?  The number of nodes or triangles  per some unit area?

The spatial resolution of the TIN. For instance, the model I made in Reality Capture is 4.204 mm² per texel.

What is the resolution of the point cloud? Is the TIN have the same resolution if you didn't filter the point cloud?

LAS in acrGIS point count is 498,682. No where does it explicitly say the resolution of the LAS file. Nor does the TIN. The TIN information is added above.

Would using total points divided by total area be a good representation of resolution? Or would 2D area divided by triangles be better?
